# Can we create a magnet with only one Pole?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a monopole magnet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34130/how-to-make-a-monopole-magnet)

No matter how many times you cut  a magnet, we always end up with 2 poles. Is there any possibility of creating a [monopole magnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34130/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1402/2451